# Output from a Recursive Function in Python

Tags: python, recursion, return, permutation

I've built the following Python function that prints permutations on sets of arbitrary length. Inputs to the function are starting index of the set (a), ending index of the set (b), and the set (e.g. [1,2,3]) and the output is [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],...]. The function written below prints the results, but what I want is a function that 'returns' the results.

```
def backtracking (a, b, seed):
if a == b:
        print(seed)
    else:
        for i in range(a, b+1):
            seed[a], seed[i] = seed[i], seed[a]
            backtracking(a + 1, b, seed)
            seed[a], seed[i] = seed[i], seed[a]

nums = [1,2,3]
backtracking(0,len(nums) - 1,list(nums))
```

The code here is an attempt to return a result, but the output is in the form [1,2,3,1,3,2,...], whereas I want [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],...]. I can easily transform the result properly later, but I would like a clean solution that directly outputs the desired result from the function. I have also tried changing line 3 to read: output += [seed], and the result is just a repeated [1,2,3] list. Similarly for output.append(seed). Why doesn't output.append(seed) append to the output properly, and how can I make it do so? Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
def backtracking (a, b, seed, output):
    if a == b:
        output += seed
    else:
        for i in range(a, b+1):
            seed[a], seed[i] = seed[i], seed[a]
            backtracking(a + 1, b, seed, output)
            seed[a], seed[i] = seed[i], seed[a]
        return(output)

nums = [1,2,3]
backtracking(0,len(nums) - 1,list(nums),[])
```

Comment: you need `output += [seed.copy()]` since you are adding the list `seed` itself so whenever see changes, all elements in output changes.

Comment: Perfect, that works!